# symbol not found Android React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, dictionary

So I'm using [this](https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl) package to try and integrate MapBox into a React-Native project I'm working on, and I keep getting this error when I run it. I've followed the instructions on their page and I'm still getting this, so I assume I forgot to install a package or something along the way. Anyone know how to fix this?

```
a:17: error: cannot find symbol
protected List getPackages() {
^
symbol: class List
location: class MainActivity
/Github/ReactApp/android/app/src/main/java/com/reactapp/MainActivity.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
protected List getPackages() {
^
symbol: class ReactPackage
location: class MainActivity
/Github/ReactApp/android/app/src/main/java/com/reactapp/MainActivity.java:16: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
@Override
^
/Github/ReactApp/android/app/src/main/java/com/reactapp/MainActivity.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
new MainReactPackage(),
^
symbol: class MainReactPackage
location: class MainActivity
/Github/ReactApp/android/app/src/main/java/com/reactapp/MainActivity.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
return Arrays.asList(
^
symbol: class ReactPackage
location: class MainActivity
/Github/ReactApp/android/app/src/main/java/com/reactapp/MainActivity.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
return Arrays.asList(
^
symbol: variable Arrays
location: class MainActivity
6 errors
```

EDIT: Here's the source code for MainActivity:

```
package com.reactapp;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import com.mapbox.reactnativemapboxgl.ReactNativeMapboxGLPackage;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "ReactApp";
    }
    @Override
  protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
      new MainReactPackage(),
      new ReactNativeMapboxGLPackage());  // <-- Register package here
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the source of your MainActivity.java file? Looks like a bunch of missing imports.

Comment: I've updated it to include the source code from MainActivity.java

Comment: Ok you're definitely missing imports. At least these two: `import java.util.List;import java.util.Arrays;`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are missing some imports:

```
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.Arrays;
 import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
 import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
```

Also one of your `@Overrides` is on a method (getPackages) that doesn't override anything from the super class. Remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing imports.

Also, if you use Android studio:

File>Settings>Editor>General>Auto Import and check

- Show import popup
- Optimize imports on the fly
- Add unambiguous imports on the fly